# Kolmogorov 0-1 law

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables

Initial question:

$X_n$, $n \in\mathbb N$, are independent real-valued random variables.  Let $S_n$ be defined, for each $n\in\mathbb N$, by the sum: $S_n = X_1+X_2+...+X_n$. Prove that either the sequence $(S_n)$, $n\in\mathbb N$ converges almost surely to an extended
real-valued random variable, or it diverges almost surely.

I know that the approach should be to show that "$(S_n)_{ n\in\mathbb N}$  converges" is a tail event, then apply Kolmogorov's 0-1 inequality to reach the required result. However, how can I show that "$(S_n)_{ n\in\mathbb N}$ converges" is a tail event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that for each $\omega$, the assertion "the sequence $(S_n(\omega))_{n\geqslant 1}$ is convergent" is equivalent to "the sequence $(S_n(\omega))_{\geqslant 1}$ is Cauchy". 
 Then notice that for each $N$ and each $\omega$, the sequence $(S_n(\omega))_{\geqslant 1}$ is Cauchy if and only if 
$$\omega\in \bigcap_{i\geqslant 1}\underbrace{\bigcup_{n\geqslant N}\bigcap_{u,v\geqslant n}\{|S_v(\omega)-S_u(\omega)|\lt 1/i\}}_{\in\sigma\left(X_l,l\geqslant N\right)}  .$$

Comment: Don't we need that set to be inside $\sigma (X_i, X_{i+1}, X_{i+2}, ...)$? And why would that be true?